# Canceling a notification from another activity - Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

When I click a button, I create a notification in Status Bar.

By being clicked, this notification creates an activity.

In the layout of this activity, there is a button.

When I click this button, the notification that created the activity where the button is, must be canceled.

The problem comes because I can create more than one notifications, giving to them different IDs.

But when I open the Status Bar, I see al the notifications, I select one, the activity is created and I click the button to cancel the activity.

**What happens is that the notification canceled is always the last created instead of being the one I selected.**

This is the code from the main activity, where notifications are created:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NotifMenuActiv extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button but_notif, but_cancel;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Notification.Builder mBuilder;
private EditText id;
private Intent resultIntent;
private PendingIntent pIntent;
private int req_code = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notif_menu);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context
            .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.joda);
    resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotifActiv.class);
    id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
    but_notif = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_notif);
    but_notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                resultIntent.putExtra("id", Integer.valueOf(id.getText().
                        toString()));
                pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                        req_code++, resultIntent, PendingIntent
                                .FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle(id.getText().toString());
                mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(id.getText().
                        toString()),mBuilder.build());
                mBuilder.setContentText(Integer.valueOf(mNotificationManager
                        .getActiveNotifications().length).toString());
                mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(id.getText().
                        toString()),mBuilder.build());

            }
        }
    });
    but_cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_cancel1);
    but_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(Integer.valueOf(id.getText().
                    toString()));
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is the onCreate method from the activity created when I click on a notification:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notif);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getIntExtra("id",id);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context
            .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    but_exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_exit);
    but_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

// This is the button that must cancel the notification that created 
// the activity
    but_cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_cancel2);

    but_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!! the solution is to give a different requestCode to each PedingIntent.

Instead of this:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Do this:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),req_code++, resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```